Property 'swiper' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "swiper/css";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from "swiper/modules";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/scrollbar";

const Testimonials = () => {
  const sliderRef = useRef(null);

  const handlePrev = useCallback(() => {
    if (!sliderRef.current) return;
    sliderRef.current.swiper.slidePrev();
  }, []);

  const handleNext = useCallback(() => {
    if (!sliderRef.current) return;
    sliderRef.current.swiper.slideNext();
  }, []);


How to solve the error above when I was using swiper library I for the testimonials section using next js and typscript
